# Python coordinate matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I need to create an array to store the coordinates at each of its positions however I don't know how to do it

[image: 1]

What I mean is that a coordinate should be assigned to a given position in the matrix such as here

```
ar2[0]=(7,2)
```

Regards, Dominik

Comment: You show a 2d array with float dtype.  What's this `ar2`, which, by the indexing should be (n,2) shape (int dtype).

Answer (score 0):

```
    ar2 = []
    ar2.append([7,2])
```

I hope this works. You have to declare ar2 as a list first then use the append() method to input the coordinates. The coordinates should be put inside [] while passing it as an argument. For adding several coordinates you might have to make use of loops.